# Who drew the Monogatari Series characters?

Tags: monogatari-series

I really love how the Monogatari Series characters are drawn, so I want to look for other art from him/her.

Here's an example of some Monogatari Series characters (clockwise, from top left):

*Senjougahara Hitagi (three times), Araragi Tsuhiki, Gaen Izuko*

[image]

My avatar is also one of the characters from the Monogatari Series; does anyone know who drew it?

Comment: My avatar is no longer one of the characters from the Monogatari Series. It was Oshino Shinobu before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is art made by [Akio Watanabe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akio_Watanabe) based on Vofan's original concept arts. The same staff have been used for all current series so far.

> The anime adaptation of Bakemonogatari aired between July 3 and September 25, 2009 on Tokyo MX. The series is part of Kodansha's Nisio Isin Anime Project and is produced by Shaft, directed by Akiyuki Shinbo with assistance from Tatsuya Oishi, written by Fuyashi Tō and featuring a character designs by Akio Watanabe based on Vofan's original concepts [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogatari_%28series%29)